# How can i get uri segment in routes?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am new to laravel and my laravel version is 5.5

In my routes file. I call `Segment` method in `Request` class

Like below :

```
var_dump(Request::segment(1));
```

And then it returns this message

```
Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::segment() should not be called statically
```

So... do I need to make new `Request` instance?

Or is there any more effective way to achieve what I want?

Any suggestion or advice would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use the [`request()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-request) global helper

```
request()->segment(1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer

I have a question.

Why laravel has a duplicate functions ?

`request` method equal `Request ` class ??

Comment: Yes, both helper and facade are just convenient shortcuts for the same functionality.

Comment: Oh.. i see, Thank you for the knowledge I didn't know.

Comment: when running `php artisan` will show an error, `Class Request not found`.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use Request class before that.

```
use Request;
var_dump(Request::segment(1));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! 
What's different 'use Illuminate\Http\Request' and 'use Request'

Comment: Oh.. 'use Request' statement not working in 'route/api'; it return this message The use statement with non-compound name 'Request' has no effect

Comment: @hax0r please refer to your `config/app.php` and you will see the different.

Comment: Why you are using it in your route?

Comment: I want to build restful api app. so i want get to global api version through uri segment

Answer (score 1):

You have to use request as

```
request()->segment(1)
```

so that error were removed.

and `request->segment(1)` is not correct way but `request()->segment(1)` is correct way to do.

i hope this works for you.